# How to compile-time detect functions that overloaded important template?

Tags: c++, c++14

Suppose we have a template:

```
template <class T>
void VeryImportantFunction(T t) {
    // something
}
```

Somewhere it is called with something like:

```
// ..
int a = 12345;
VeryImportantFunction(a);
// ..
```

It is very big project with tons of source code, and occasionally somewhere in deep of the code appears a new header with overloaded function:

```
void VeryImportantFunction(int t) {
    // totally another behavior
}
```

And code fragment above will call overloaded function, because it have more priority.

Can we somehow disable or in another way compile-time detect functions that can overload our important template?

Comment: Use namespaces and tell users to Read The Fine Manual.

Comment: @PasserBy "for all good and against all bad", yes, I agree with you. BUT.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is unclear, but here's my take on it.

---

If you want to hit the template overload, you can simply invoke the function by explicitly specifying the template parameters:

```
int a = 12345;
VeryImportantFunction<int>(a);
```

---

If you want this from happening again in the future, then make `VeryImportantFunction` either a lambda or a `struct` - those cannot be overloaded "externally":

```
inline const auto VeryImportantFunction = [](auto x){ /* ... */ };
// no one can overload this!
```

---

If you want to know all the overloads of `VeryImportantFunction` without external tooling, then call it in a completely wrong way - the compiler error will likely show all considered overloads:

```
VeryImportantFunction(5, 5, 5, 5); 
// error... will likely show all candidates
```

Comment: In case OP uses function pointer, `&VeryImportantFunction<int>` should be replaced by `&VeryImportantFunction::operator<int>()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 One could always overload `&` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
inline void VeryImportantFunction(int t)
{ 
    VeryImportantFunction<int>(t); // call the template function
}
```

immediately after your template definition.

Then if someone has written their own version of `void VeryImportantFunction(int t)`, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: I don't think that OP will do it for each types to protect of overloads...

Comment: @Jarod42: For me the question reads that the only function they need to avoid is the `int` one.